# Clicking "No" on a message box results in the data still being saved to the database

Tags: c#, mysql, messagebox

If I click the "No" button at `MessageBoxButton.YesNo` the data that is being typed is still inserting in the database. How should I fix this?

This is my code:

```
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO db_personal(per_image,per_Fname,per_Mname,per_Lname)VALUES(@per_image,@per_Fname,@per_Mname,@per_Lname)";

connection.Open();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_image", newPicture.Image);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_Fname", newFirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_Mname", newMiddleName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_Lname", newLastName.Text);

try
{
    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
    {
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "New student information has been successfully saved.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Incomplete information. Are you sure you want to save?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

connection.Close();
```

Comment: Check what the MessageBox call returns.

Comment: well... don't execute the query until *after* they select yes

Comment: Your code snippet doesnt show any message box handling

Comment: You need to do something with the result i.e. `if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)` Also you run the query then ask if the user wants to save the data, at which point it probably already has, think about doing a re-design and check the input data before running the query

Comment: `if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)` look at @TheLethalCoder's answer for the rest

Comment: It doesn't look like you are ever checking to see if the information is "incomplete". I would design it as follows.

1. Check if information is complete.
  a. If incomplete, present message box with Yes, No. If Yes, proceed to executenonquery. if No, exit method.
 b. if information complete, proceed to executenonqueery and supply messagebox that information added.

Answer (score 1):

First off you run the query:

```
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
```

And check the result to see what message you want to show. At this point the data is either already saved to the database or not. You then ask the user if they still want to save the data to the database but do nothing with that information, you'd want to do something like:

```
DialogResult dr = MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Incomplete information. Are you sure you want to save?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //Handle saving, although it probably already has been
    //Ask to re-enter the data?
}
else
{
    //Rollback the previous command
}
```

I have never had to rollback a command to a database but I found the method [SqlTransaction.Rollback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayx5s0h(v=vs.110).aspx), although I don't know how it works or if it is applicable.

You should think about redoing your logic so that it flows better:

1. Check the input data looks as expected, all validation routines
2. Ask the user if they really want to save the information
3. **IF** yes save the data

So something like:

```
//Some validation

DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the information?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //Do something with the result here
}
```

If the validation check fails but it is still compatible with the database you could also present the user with a message if they still want to continue:

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Incomplete information. Are you sure you want to save?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
if (dr != DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //Do not save the data
}
```